# Difference in hours between 2 dates not working during daylight savings

Tags: javascript

I have 2 dates with time that I would like to see the difference of hours. When running overnight crossing daylight savings it is ignoring daylight savings. This is what I am trying. Date of time in is `March 8th 11 PM` and Time out is `March 9th 7 AM`. Expected to get 7 hours but it is returning 8

```
var hours = Math.abs(objTimeIn.valueOf() - objTimeOut.valueOf()) / 36e5;
```

Comment: In what time zone? Not all time zones have DST. Can you show us where you are initializing the dates?

Comment: This could get complex - do you know that your user is in a timezone with daylight savings?  I would think you would need to know the user's location and accommodate that.   Also - what are you trying to accomplish?  If it is elapsed time, then you want to ignore daylight savings, otherwise your numbers will be wrong.

Comment: This is why most time sensitive software switches to using UTC.

Comment: DST's depend on the timezone. For example, here, in France, we go forward in April (not March), and back in October (not November).

Answer (score 0):

You need to care about the current timezone offset of the date.
You can use this piece of code

```js
var d1 = new Date("03-10-2015");
var d2 = new Date("03-08-2015");

// Retrieve timezone offsets
var dst1 = d1.getTimezoneOffset();
var dst2 = d2.getTimezoneOffset();

// get the diff between the two dates
var diff = d1 - d2;

// timezone offset
var add = (dst2 - dst1) * 60 * 1000;

// add the offset
var ms = diff + add;

console.log(ms/36e5);
```